# rename upload file, post new name to database

Tags: php, mysql, upload, rename

I'm using the following code to upload and rename files. That part works awesome, however it also posts some data to a db table.

The problem is the old name is getting posted to the db, but the file is renaming to the ID...how can I get the new name into the db?

Thanks in advance here is my code:

```
 <?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.pdf','.xlsx','.xls','.doc','.docx','.ppt','.pptx','.jpeg','.png','.gif','.pdf');
$max_filesize = 52428800; // max file size = 50MB
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['document']['name']);


//This gets all the other information from the form
$billing_id=$_POST['billing_id'];
$shipping_id=$_POST['shipping_id'];
$file_name=$_POST['file_name'];
$file_type=$_POST['file_type'];
$file_description=$_POST['file_description'];

        $file = $_FILES['document']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
        $ext = substr($file, strpos($file,'.'), strlen($file)-1);
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))//check if file type is allowed
            die('The file extension you attempted to upload is not allowed.'); //not allowed
        if(filesize($_FILES['document']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) //check that filesize is less than 50MB
            die ('The file you attempted to upload is too large, compress it below 50MB.');


// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("table") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_files (billing_id, shipping_id, file_name, file_type, file_description, file)
VALUES ('$billing_id', '$shipping_id', '$file_name', '$file_type', '$file_description', '$target')") ;

$target = "../../file_management/uploads/customers/" .mysql_insert_id() . $ext; 

//Writes the file to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['document']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting the values to the database before you are renaming the file. You have to make change in your code. First insert the billing and shipping id in the databse, then take the last inserted id, rename the file with the last insert id and update the new name in databse. Change your code to:

```
<?php

   //This is the directory where images will be saved
   $allowed_filetypes =array('.jpg','.pdf','.xlsx','.xls','.doc','.docx','.ppt','.pptx','.jpeg','.png','.gif','.pdf');
   $max_filesize = 52428800; // max file size = 50MB
   $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['document']['name']);


   //This gets all the other information from the form
  $billing_id=$_POST['billing_id'];
  $shipping_id=$_POST['shipping_id'];
  $file_name=$_POST['file_name'];
  $file_type=$_POST['file_type'];
  $file_description=$_POST['file_description'];

    $file = $_FILES['document']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
    $ext = substr($file, strpos($file,'.'), strlen($file)-1);
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))//check if file type is allowed
        die('The file extension you attempted to upload is not allowed.'); //not allowed
    if(filesize($_FILES['document']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) //check that filesize is less than 50MB
        die ('The file you attempted to upload is too large, compress it below 50MB.');


    // Connects to your Database
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
     mysql_select_db("table") or die(mysql_error()) ;

    //Writes the information to the database
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_files (billing_id, shipping_id) VALUES ('$billing_id', '$shipping_id')") ;

  $target = "../../file_management/uploads/customers/" .mysql_insert_id() . $ext; 

  $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
  $new_file_name = mysql_insert_id() . $ext;

  mysql_query("UPDATE customer_files SET file_name='$new_file_name',file_type='$file_type',file_description='$file_description',file='$target' WHERE id=$last_id");


//Writes the file to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['document']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

 //Tells you if its all ok
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Sabari, this did exactly what I was hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The new 'name' is already in the DB - it's the primary key of the record that was created when you inserted the upload data:

```
$target = "../../file_management/uploads/customers/" .mysql_insert_id() . $ext;
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the new filename
```

Comment: ^ This and also your code is very vulnerable to sql injections. How do you know the user entered a number into $_POST['billing_id'];
and not "x'; DROP TABLE customer_files; --" (Thus destroying your table!). I guess you are new to PHP so you might want to take some time reading about sql injects and the like and how you can escape the input data. Never trust user input!

Comment: I know that, but I need the path so i can link to it..the path used is whatever the file is actually called from the up-loader's desktop. Since multiple extensions can be used I can just link to the id

Comment: No, you've saved the file onto your server using the path I copy/pasted into my answer, with the ID of the database record. It's NOT saved with the original filename on the user's machine. That exists ONLY inside your database, NOT on the file system.

Comment: Yeah however, the value for file is $target. which say file is called: blah.png, will upload to file path as blah.png, but will save the file as 123.png

Comment: Don't save it with an extension, just save it with the ID number. Then you provide a script which gives access to the file via the id number, e.g. 'file.php?id=123'. That script issues appropriate content-disposition headers which provide the ORIGINAL filename from your database.